# Which is the real character level in Rift?

Tags: rift

I'm just starting out with Rift, I can see **level 18** on my character panel. But, below the portrait at top-left corner, the **level shown there is 10**.

I'm still playing in Silverwood. Which is my correct character level? I guess the smaller number is not my mentoring level as level 18 is still too low.

Comment: The character level is under portrait. The number a bit to the left (can be seen on [this screenshot](https://www.f2p.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Rift-screenshots-23.jpg)) is a certain currency. I forgot which one exactly, since not playing Rift for a while, I recall (but not sure) it has something to do with rifts.

Comment: but in the character panel, the level is different

Comment: Uh, I miss that point. Could you attach a screenshot or find one? Check if there is a tooltip explaining what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real character level is 18, but you have mentored down and your effective level is 10.  At level 15, you got a quest that taught you how to mentor down, so that's probably why you're 10. Certain areas, like nightmare rifts (with all the eyeballs) also automatically mentor you down.

You can clear your mentor level by right-clicking your portrait.

Also by right clicking your portrait, you can choose to enable sidekicking. This will *increase* your level, up to a limit per zone, when you group with a higher level player.